# Definition of curves.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, curves, low-dimensional-topology

To define a regular smooth curve in $\mathbb R^3$ one can take some parametrization $(x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t))$ with the velocity vector $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is not equal to zero (it is the regularity condition). It is well known that locally every regular smooth curve is a solution for equation system $F_1 = F_2 = 0$ of maximal rank. It has obvious generalization to an higher dimensional submanifolds, e.g. for surfaces in $\mathbb R^4$. And it also well known that in general embedded submanifold can not be represented as a solution of equations(with maximal rank condition) $globally$, e.g. $\mathbb{RP}^2$ embedded in $\mathbb R^4$. The question is simple. Is there any regular closed smooth curve $(x_1(t), x_2(t), x_3(t))$ with the velocity vector $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is not equal to zero such that it can not be globally represented as a solution of regular equation system: $F_1 = F_2 = 0$, ${\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}}$ has rank = 2.

Comment: UPD: It should be closed curve, I'm sorry.

Comment: This is true (for curves in $R^n$) and follows from existence of a tubular neighborhood around the curve. Are you familiar with tubular neighborhoods?

Comment: Yes, it is something I am familiar, but still don't got your point.

Comment: And question is all about $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider the case of a trivial vector bundle over the circle. You realize zero section of the bundle as the regular zero level set of a compactly supported map on the total space of the bundle. Next, the normal bundle of any smoothly embedded circle in the Euclidean space is trivial. Lastly use the fact that a tubular neighborhood if such circle is diffeomorphic to the total space of the normal bundle .

Comment: These functions will be defined only locally, in general, I can not see any way to define them globally without some additional intersection set.

Comment: @Rick_Student: Did you understand what I wrote?

Comment: I suppose so. The problem is about finding globally defined function $F$ and $G$ such that its zeroes set is given smooth closed curve. $F$ and $G$ is supposed to be transversal. Your answer is like take tubular neighborhood and take $F$ and $G$ - coordinates in normal bundle. The point is such a functions defined locally.